# Error when sending an email from the shell using sendEmail

Tags: linux, email, shell

I'm using [sendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) to send emails using google account .. it is working fine on number of identical servers but on one if the servers it gives me the following error

> smtp.gmail.com:587 failed: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection
>   refused

i also tried ssmtp but i also received a similar socket error

any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue... Are you able to ping and telnet to the server i.e. `ping smtp.gmail.com` ;  `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested you can reach the server from the box e.g.

```
$ ping  smtp.gmail.com
64 bytes from wi-in-f108.1e100.net (173.194.67.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=26.9 ms
64 bytes from wi-in-f108.1e100.net (173.194.67.108): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=27.0 ms
^C


$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

Trying 173.194.67.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP hg17sm2838358wib.1 - gsmtp
^]
telnet> quit
```

Press **CTRL+]** and type **quit** to exit.

If not check you local firewall.

Comment: I'm able to ping but the connection is refused when i telnet .... i have another server in the same location that i can communicate normally so i guess the problem is related to this specific server socket

Comment: What do you get from a: sudo "iptables -L -n"

Comment: Also read the following two questions  [1](http://serverfault.com/questions/91595/without-iptables-telnet-smtp-gmail-com-465-fine-with-no-go-however-ports-ou), [2](http://serverfault.com/questions/350071/iptables-allow-connections-on-a-port-to-only-safe-hosts)

Comment: Actually this is a firewall with shorewall installed, what i reached now is shorewall is rejecting the connection from the server to the smtp.gmail.com and here is the log ... however how can i modify this and configure shorewall to accept?

Shorewall:fw2net:REJECT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=X.X.X.X DST=74.125.25.108 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43820 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58025 DPT=587 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: By adding a series of **accept** rules to the /etc/shorewall/ config e.g.

    ACCEPT   loc             173.194.67.108    tcp    587
    ACCEPT   $FW             173.194.67.108    tcp    587

Comment: Thanks telnetting to the gmail server was the right steps to solve the problem , i edited the fw rules